# Remove two words after a specific word

Tags: php, regex

How to remove two words after a specific word in string? For example, I have this sentence that end with a period:

```
$sentence = 'hello stackoverflow remove string bla bla bla.';
$specificword = 'stackoverflow';
```

I want to remove 'remove' and 'string', and output this:

```
$output = 'hello stackoverflow bla bla bla.';
```

Another better option if possible will be: to remove two words after the specific word if `strlen` of word1 and word2 is >5, if `strlen` of word1 >5 and `strlen` of word2 <5 don't remove.

Comment: Hi, show us what you have tried, edit your question to include your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simply remove the two words, you can use [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace):

```
$new_sentence = str_replace(array('remove', 'string'), '', $sentence);
```

If you want to check the length of the two words after the specified string, then you'll want to extract the words first. You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) and [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos) to get the part of the sentence after the specified word and then use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) to split the sentence with a space as the delimiter:

```
$specific_word_pos = strpos($sentence, $specificword) + strlen($specificword);
$sentence_part = substr($sentence, $specific_word_pos);
$words = explode(' ', trim($sentence_part));

// check the word lengths and do the removal    
if (strlen($words[0]) > 5 && strlen($words[1]) > 5 ) {
    $new_sentence = str_replace(array('remove', 'string'), '', $sentence);
} else {
    // some code
}

echo $new_sentence; // => hello stackoverflow  bla bla bla.
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/80034)

Comment: thank you Amal,works very good. i replace this line : `$new_sentence = str_replace(array($words[0], $words[1]), '', $sentence);` in case we dont know the words.

Comment: @mwweb: Yeah, that's a good idea. Glad to have been of help :) Please mark this answer as **[accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)** if it answers your question :)

Comment: Amal is any option to explde the string without using `explode` ?because i think perform slow with a large string. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression with a positive lookbehind to do this.

```
$s = 'hello stackoverflow remove string bla bla bla.';

$output = preg_replace('/(?<=stackoverflow)(\s+)\w{5,}\s+\w{5,}\s+/ui', '$1', $s);

echo $output, PHP_EOL; // hello stackoverflow bla bla bla.
```

`(?<=stackoverflow)` tells the pattern that it must be preceded by "stackoverflow", replace this with whatever your `$specifiedword` is. We use a positive look behind to say, "stackoverflow followed by two words that are at least five characters long separated by spaces"

- `(?<=stackoverflow)` -- positive lookbehind to match specified word
- `\s+` -- one or more space characters
- `\w{5,}` -- at least five word characters

Comment: Thank you Chris. i think this will perform much faster than Amal Murali answer am i right?

Comment: Probably. Honestly I don't know enough about the internals of the PHP regex engine to give you a good answer to that.